# What exactly happened at the end of Voyager: "Endgame"?

Tags: star-trek, star-trek-voyager, borg, transwarp

The final episode of *Star Trek: Voyager*, "Endgame" has this sequence:

- **Voyager enters transwarp tunnel**.
- **Sphere seen bearing down on Voyager**
- **Sphere exits tunnel + explodes**

At this point, the visuals seem a bit unclear, but the dialog and description in the [transcript](http://www.chakoteya.net/Voyager/722.htm) seem to corroborate the idea that somehow Voyager was ***inside* the sphere.**

So just how did the Voyager get there? Or does "*right where we expect it to be*" just mean the Alpha quadrant hidden close to the sphere and they explode the sphere from inside by some other trickery and/or excellent marksmanship?

Was this some sort of plan? What was Janeway's 'endgame' in Endgame?

Comment: I'm not quite sure what you're asking. Are you wanting to know how the Voyager ended up inside the Borg Sphere?

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Wvqme6qYtME

Comment: @Valorum:   Essentially yes, if that is indeed what is supposed to have happened.

Comment: Hmm. That's quite a good point. It's not clear from the script, the actual episode or the novel quite **how** the Borg took the Voyager inside, nor **why** they'd have done that in the first place.

Comment: The novelisation is no help at all "*"Captain, a Borg sphere is bearing down on our stern," Tuvok warned quickly.
 
The sphere immediately opened up on the ship, chewing away at the armor around the nacelles and engineering hull and the aft end of the saucer section.
 
Tuvok frowned. "Armor is eroding steadily!"
 
"Increase speed," Janeway ordered.
 
"Captain!"
 
Janeway looked up at Tom Paris's warning cry at the main screen. Before them the corridor between quadrants was collapsing in on itself!*" The next scene is the Sphere emerging from the conduit

Comment: It seems the explanation is missing in favor of being a surprising revelation to the audience.   Maybe they deleted some exposition ("Hey, good thing you futuristic metaphasic cloak let us fly into the sphere undetected."), because it was lame or ruined the flow.    Looks like we need a shooting script or a comment from the production staff or something.

Comment: Lol. I think what happened was the show got cancelled and they needed a way to wrap it up immediately. Star Trek has a way of using the word "somehow" which excuses them from needing to explain anything. Think First Contact when they are following the Borg back to Earth and they get a glimpse of the world taken over. Looks like Endgame employed "somehow" without actually having to say it.

Comment: I'm struggling to find a script. There's a few for sale but I refuse to pay cold hard cash for something that will eventually turn up on the internet.

Comment: Of interest, but not enlightening: http://www.trektoday.com/news/060601_03.shtml

Comment: I've done a big edit to see if I can make the question a little clearer. Hope it's not too much.

Comment: @Valorum: In the clip that you linked to, what happened to Chakotay's face tattoo? When he relieves Paris and takes the helm his face tattoo is missing.

Comment: @sfhq_sf - Production dun goofed. I read somewhere that he wiped it off for the "end of series" photos, but then realised he was supposed to be still in character dress. Maybe this shot took place between that and him putting it back on.

Comment: @ThePopMachine : Just saw this question now.  I watched this episode a couple of months ago (I had rewatched *Voyager* from beginning to end).  I had the same question in my mind after the episode, too.  +1

Comment: @Valorum, your edit is fine,  although I'd keep the transcript for clarity,  for reference,  and for those who may not be in a situation where they can watch the video.

Comment: @sfhq_sf I can't see the clip (it's been taken down) but I just checked on the full episode and it's definitelty there when he takes the helm. Perhaps the clip was low quality, and it was hard to see?

Answer (score 7):

[Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Endgame_%28Star_Trek:_Voyager%29#Plot) gives the details of how the Borg are destroyed.

I found a reference that the Borg were chasing Voyager with an entry open and overtook it as they reached the Alpha quadrant. While the Borg were fighting the fleet, Voyager launched torpedoes from inside. The following from the script gives the implication, however I do not have the novel reference

[Endgame script](http://www.chakoteya.net/Voyager/722.htm)

> (The Sphere prepares to activate its tractor beam.)
>   PARIS: I can't stay ahead of them, Captain.
>   JANEWAY: Mister Paris, prepare to adjust your heading.
>   PARIS: Yes, ma'am.

This implies that the script statement means that they realize that the sphere will pull them in and will be vulnerable to the torpedoes.

[Memory Alpha Wiki](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Endgame_%28episode%29) hints the same thing but deliberately obfuscates the description.

[Endgame (Star Trek: Voyager)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Endgame_%28Star_Trek:_Voyager%29#Plot)

> Meanwhile Captain Janeway and her crew have entered a transwarp
>   corridor and fire torpedoes at the unprotected manifolds while
>   traveling back to the Alpha Quadrant, but are pursued by a Borg sphere
>   that has managed to withstand the pathogen's effects and assimilate
>   Admiral Janeway's adaptive armor upgrade. It is now following the Borg
>   Queen's final orders to destroy Voyager so that the Admiral (and her
>   sabotage) will never exist. Unable to fight back against the ship's
>   exterior defenses, Janeway takes her ship inside the sphere, where,
>   upon its arrival one lightyear away from Earth's solar system, she
>   detonates a torpedo that destroys the sphere from the inside.
>
> In the show's final minutes, the crew stand dumbfounded that they have
>   finally returned home after seven years lost in the Delta Quadrant and
>   are greeted by a fleet of Starfleet vessels which had arrived to fight
>   the Borg. Settling down in her chair, Captain Janeway issues her final
>   orders with the same words she used at the start of Voyager's journey:
>   "Set a course...for home."

Comment: *"Unable to fight back against the ship's exterior defenses, Janeway takes her ship inside the sphere"*  -I'm unclear where the Wiki got that from.

Comment: @Valorum:   Yes, exactly.   Or how?    That's the crux of the question.

Comment: @sabbahillel - That link appears to be a fan-written wiki page.

Comment: I'm not convinced the ship is supposed to be in the sphere.  They could just be hiding behind it.

Comment: @Valorum I fixed the typo.

Comment: @ThePopMachine The armor of the sphere would have protected it "behind" just as well as "in front". It is not like a surface ship or tank that would have a difference in armor on the front or sides. That is another reason to be a sphere (besides the volume to surface area ratio and the ability to fight in all three dimensions).

Comment: @sabbahillel, that argument presupposes that Voyager wasnt able to destroy the sphere merely because of their enhanced technology and/or the weakened state of the sphere.

Comment: _"It is now following the Borg Queen's final orders to destroy Voyager so that the Admiral (and her sabotage) will never exist"_ That makes no sense. This is clearly already an alternate reality so destroying Voyager is not going to have any effect on what's already happened in this episode.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit - Agreed. The Borg want to study the tech, not simply destroy it.

Comment: @ThePopMachine The clip linked in the question shows the sphere opening up to take in Voyager at 0:40

Comment: Well going inside the Sphere happened in Elite Force 2 but I'm that's Memory Beta content

Comment: @Izkata:   It does show the sphere opening up.   If you say to say *to take in Voyager*, you are assuming a particular intent.   That is not at all clear.   And why would the Borg do that, when it is clear they are vulnerable from in the inside?   They would be better off just firing on Voyager, or ramming it, or shutting down the transwarp network.

Comment: @ThePopMachine My guess would be they planned on self-destruct with Voyager inside

Comment: @ThePopMachine Borg programming is to assimilate if possible. They apparently thought that they could convert Voyager before it could do damage.

Answer (score 7):

According to Captain Picard (as narrated in the PC game [Star Trek: Elite Force II](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Star_Trek:_Elite_Force_II)), the Voyager was captured by the Borg Sphere on its trip through the Transwarp tunnel network and held in a dampening field, presumably for later study after the Borg had dealt with the more immediate threat of the tunnels collapsing behind them.

After somehow deactivating the field (in the game this was accomplished by the Hazard Squad) and determining that the ship was indeed in the Alpha Quadrant, Voyager used one of her enhanced quantum torpedoes to destroy the Sphere from the inside-out before scarpering at high speed from the wreckage.

As to the question of *planning*, it seems abundantly clear that this was something that Janeway improvised after she realised that she could neither outrun the Sphere, nor make it to the next off-ramp. When she ordered Paris to

> "*adjust your heading*"

she was evidently doing so in a way that would allow the Sphere to capture the Voyager, but that would also make it impossible for them to exit the tunnel network anywhere other than the Alpha Quadrant, right where they expected to be.

Comment: Maybe this is the 'canon' way it happened, but it's incredibly poor, "The Last Jedi" style writing where completely weird, impossible stuff happens every minute or two with no explanation of how.  Then some twit on Twitters later explains how it might have happened, or the writers later think something up and stick it in a game.  Either way, you just have to accept "it's magic" because the writers are just SO awful.

Answer (score 0):

I found the moments before leaving the transwarp conduit to be confusing as well. Chakotay asked how long until the nearest conduit exit and Seven tells him "30 seconds away, but it will deposit them back into the Delta Quadrant" but Voyager did not go back to the Delta quadrant and they seemingly adjusted their heading to go inside the sphere. 
If the Borg were able to implement the special shielding acquired by the Borg Queen while chasing Voyager then the only way to destroy the sphere was to get inside of it.
Perhaps this was a misplaced suspense element that was never clarified.

Comment: I'm having a bit of trouble with your answer, could you [edit] it to make it a bit clearer? It also looks like there's some off-topic stuff as well as maybe a question in there. Please only use the answer box to answer questions. If you have a new questions press the [Ask Question](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/ask) button. Thanks and have a nice day.

Comment: This seems to be an extended comment rather than an answer in its own right.

Comment: "There is no good answer" is an answer, too.  And in this case, I think this is the correct answer.  Basically, the writers got lazy and decided to give up and blatantly leave out the segment.  So the end became an incoherent mess the writers decided to fill in in a later PC game.

Answer (score 0):

I always assumed that their ability to "wear" the Borg ship without getting assimilated had to do with the Borg being infected with the SpaceHerp that future Janeway infected them with via her own bloodstream when the queen tries to assimilate her (Future Janeway).  the death of the queen would probably wreak enough havoc with the Borg systems, possibly even killing them, that they wouldn't be in any state to defend themselves, which would include shielding, repair, etc...

Comment: This seems more like a comment than an answer in its own right.

Comment: You may be right - that's what I get for trying to add something in at work!

Comment: @Valorum No it doesn't.  It's an attempted answer, an educated guess essentially, since the episode itself did not fill in any of the necessary details to understand the most important plot point of the entire series.  Answers don't have to be provably correct!

Comment: @ChrisBordeman - In the absence of anything to back it up, answers based on mere supposition are (imho) better posted as comments.

Comment: @Valorum All the answers are 'mere suppositions' since the episode didn't answer the question.  Without the follow up game, it's total guesswork how it got there, writing at its worst.

Answer (score -1):

(if I remember correctly)

Voyager was tractor-beamed inside the Borg sphere just as it arrives in the Alpha Quadrant; and they just blasted their way out at the same time the rest of the fleet pounded on the Sphere.

At the same time, Voyager triggered the destruction of the Transwarp infrastructure; which more or less removed the Borg threats by removing their mode of transportation.

They just ended the Borg game.